# When I try to store a character it stores it as a int. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: c, char, int

Why when i try to store a character it stores it as a int in C 
So I have the code:

```
char p = (char)'w';

tree_insert(&root,p);
```

however its just passes the number 119 instead of the actual letter w, but i need it to pass the letter w.

Any would help would be great
This is my declaration of tree_insert incase you need it:

```
void tree_insert ( struct Tree_Node**root, char letter );
```

Comment: How do you know? The letter `w` __is__ the number 119.

Comment: When I hover the mouse over the character it says (int) 119 and then if I try printing it out , it prints 119

Comment: Then you're not printing the character correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking at this value? If you are using printf, it's important to make sure you are printing out the variable in the right way. This code should print your char:

```
    printf("%c\n", p);
```

I suspect that your print statement has a `%d` where I have placed the `%c`. The reason this happens is because C stores chars in 8 bits, for your char `'w'`:

```
    0 1 1 1  0 1 1 1
    bin -> dec = 119
```

When you tell C to print these 8 bits as a char, it has to know how to interpret them. You use the [format specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) to tell C what the heck it's looking at.

Comment: But it’s passing 119 to the function instead of the letter w

Comment: Yes, it is, because `119 == 'w'`

Comment: But how i get it to pass the w?

Comment: @David Neill Computers can **only** process numbers. So, all characters have been mapped to some specific numbers. Google for 'ASCII table', for a start. Later, you might want to examine UTF-8 for character representation.